# Vertical lines on LCD and all computer text scrambled

Tags: motherboard, crash

A few days ago, my system was working fine, but lately my home electricity has been flutuating many times in a day. Now, my computer has stopped working properly. Those problems happen:

1. When I play a video, it hangs.
2. When I open Mozilla Firefox the system hangs.
3. System also hangs sometimes, just after a few minutes running.
4. Sometimes some vertical lines displayed on my HCL LCD and the BIOS text gets scrambled or converted into a strange font that cant be understand.
5. When I reset the RAM and graphics card, it works fine for a while and then again starts problems occuring.

Is my hardware damaged? If yes, which device?

My computer configurations are below:
Core 2 Duo CPU, 2 GB RAM, Gigabyte motherboard, Nvidia 8500 GT graphics card, SATA hard disk.

Answer (score 4):

The symptoms you describe suggest a RAM or motherboard problem. I would try running [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) first, to see if the RAM has gone bad. If the RAM comes back clean, or if the computer hangs during the test, your motherboard has probably developed an issue.

If you're having power fluctuation issues, you might want to take a look at an uninterruptable power supply.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe suggest problems in either RAM, video card or motherboard.

Specially the problem you describe (garbled characters in the BIOS) point at one (or both) of the first two items: try another RAM module and/or another video card and see if the problem persists.

Also, run Memtest86+ as proposed by another answer, and try another power supply (unlikely to be the cause of this problem, but a PSU can be damaged by a power fluctuation).